# How to add a counter in laravel eloquent when getting data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I add a counter in select when fetching data using laravel eloquent? Please see my code below.

**Eloquent**

```
return JobOrder::select([
           DB::raw('SET @counter = 0; (@counter := @counter+1) as index'),
           'job_order_id',
           'job_order_code',
           'job_title',
           'job_overview',
           'posting_date',
           'visibility_order'
       ])
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET
> @counter = 0; (@counter := @counter+1) as index

Comment: Have you tried running a separate `DB::select('SET @counter = 0')` command, and then using the `@counter` variable in your `SELECT` query?

Comment: @fubar yes but it still returns the same error

Answer (score 0):

- You need to set the variable `@counter` in a separate statement.
- `index` is a reserved keyword. If you want it to be an alias for a column, you must put it in quotes.

```php
DB::statement('SET @counter = 0');

return JobOrder::select([
    DB::raw('(@counter := @counter + 1) as "index"'),
    'job_order_id',
    'job_order_code',
    'job_title',
    'job_overview',
    'posting_date',
    'visibility_order'
])
```